# How to convert a stream into an object in Ruby

Tags: json, ruby, sinatra

I am attempting to make a PUT fetch request from my jQuery file. The server giving me a 500, as the fetch is not able to be used by my controller. 
This is the stream that is being sent to my .rb file in the form of request.body:

```
request.body == #<StringIO:0x00005597c3b69fa8>
request.body.string == "{\"name\":\"New School\",\"office_id\":2,\"inactive\":false}"
```

I have tried..

```
load(request.body.string)
```

But this returns a load error:

```
LoadError: cannot load such file -- {"name":"New School","office_id":2,"inactive":false}
```

Also..

```
parse(request.body.string)
```

which results in

```
undefined method `parse' for #<CrEventsApp:0x00005597c3bbf098>
```

Is there a method that will parse this information back into a hash? I can parse through the string myself with some regex and .split() to get the data into a useable format, but I would like a more concise and robust solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JSON.parse](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-parse) should do the trick:

```
JSON.parse(request.body.string)
=> {"name"=>"New School", "office_id"=>2, "inactive"=>false}
```

Comment: Oh, wow, that totally worked. Gives me my object back just the way I ported it over. Thank you for clearing that up!